# Парсинг. Объединить улицу и номер дома

Tags: python, парсер

Как выбрать улицу и приписать к ней номера домов, которые находятся внутри страницы улицы, т.е объединить улицу и номера домов?

Код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://xn--80ap2aj.xn--80asehdb/40c6863e-2a5f-4033-a377-3416533948bd/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

for a in soup.select('div.col-md-3.col-sm-6 > a'):
    print(a.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Я делаю так: `for street, homeNumb in zip(data, data):`
street - возвращает улицу
homeNimb - возвращает номер дома
data - переменная в которой находится div блок в который входит и улица и номер дома.

Например:

```
data = bs.allfind("div", class_="(название класса)")

    for street, homeNumb in zip(data, data):
        street = title.find("h3", itemprop="название класса или что там есть на сайте").text.strip()
        homeNumb = price.find("span", class_="название класса или что там есть на сайте").text.strip()
        print("Улица: " + street + " Номер Дома: " + homeNumb)
```

Comment: вся загвоздка, что необходимо перейти по ссылке, прежде чем перейдешь к странице, которая содержит нумерацию домов, т.е дома проходят отдельно: один элемент находится внутри другого элемента (улица содержит в себе номера домов и чтобы увидеть данную информацию необходимо перейти по ссылке: тык на нужную улицу, открывает страницу с нумерацией домов. В конечном итоге необходимо приписать номер домов к данной улице